# .NET Regex's Match class: What's the match name?

Tags: .net, regex, .net-core

The `Match` class has a name property, but that is always `"0"`.

In particular,

```
Regex.Matches("abcd", "b|d")
```

gives two matches that I that can only be distinguished by value. Same with replacements:

```
Regex.Replace("abcd", "b|d", m => m.Name) // gives a0b0
```

This above gives `a0b0`, so the name doesn't tell them apart, nor does anything else in the `Match` class.

Other groups don't help either, since

```
Regex.Replace("abcdef", "(b)|(d)|(f)", m => m.Groups.Count.ToString())
```

gives `a4c4e4`, so in each match evaluation all groups are the same in the match.

That means while it is possible to use the *actually matched string*, ie. the value, it's not possible to know anything else about it, such as which sub-pattern in the regex it was matched by.

This is needed running multiple different replacements with one replace call, which is potentially much faster than using one replace call per pattern, if there are a lot of replacement patterns.

Is this sad conclusion correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace("abcdef", "(b)|(d)|(f)", m => m.Groups.Values.Skip(1).First(g => g.Success).Name)
```

This will give you `a1c2e3` which is probably what you want if I understood your question correctly.

You need to skip `m.Groups[0]` because it is same for all matches. And `m.Groups` contains all groups in your original regex regardless if they matched or not. So you can filter the group by success like in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

One can name match capture groups by using this pattern

```
(?<YourValueHere>.+)
```

and then extract as such

```
myMatch.Group["YourValueHere"].Value
```

This comes in handy when indexing into a match may be problematic such as this

```
((abc)|(def))? (GHI)
```

will the match group index of "GHI" capture be 1 or 2? To avoid that name the matches such as

```
((?<Name>abc)|(?<Rank>def))? (?<SerialNumber>GHI)
```

Then you can check/ extract as such

```
 if (myMatch.Group["Rank"].IsSuccess)
      rank = myMatch.Group["Rank"].Value

 var SerialNumber = myMatch.Group["SerialNumber"].Value;
```